# In Java, how do I properly use an abstract classes in method Parameters?

Tags: java, class, inheritance, abstract, extends

I have an abstract class the looks like this:

```
public abstract class Mapper<T>{
    public T getResult(String json){
        ...
    }
}
```

T is an object class that the json string gets mapped to.

I have several mapping classes that extend this abstract class; all with different T values. What I want is to be able to plug the parent Mapper class into a method that all the children classes can use; so I don't have to write a separate method for each child class. My expected method looks like this:

```
public handleResult(String 1, String 2, boolean 3, Mapper<T> map){
    ....
}
```

This is giving me issue that it cannot resolve T, and I have tried it like this:

```
public handleResult(String 1, String 2, boolean 3, Mapper map){
    ....
}
```

However that causes null pointer issues because it cannot resolve what T is suppose to be further into the the code.

Can anyone guide me as to how I can use this abstract class in the method?

Comment: By making the declaring class or the method generic, you can define the `T` type parameter, after that, you can use it

Comment: Why is your method don't have any return type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method should look like this

```
public <T> T handleResult(String p1, String p2, boolean p3, Mapper<T> map){
    ...
}
```

Or if it shouldn't return anything:

```
public <T> void handleResult(String p1, String p2, boolean p3, Mapper<T> map){
    ...
}
```